# Trying to open .txt in Delphi XE 5

Tags: delphi

I'm getting the same error repeatedly and I really don't know why.

In my code, I'm testing to see if the .txt exists, it does, but still gives me the error "Can't find file location".

I used the following code:

```
 IF Not FileExists('Some.txt') then
    ShowMessage('Some message');
```

I did place the .txt file in the same folder as the program itself, but it still says it fails to find it.

I've gotten it to work like this:

```
 IF Not FileExists('F:\Delphi\TextFiles\Some.txt') then
    ShowMessage('Some message');
```

On Delphi 2010, it works without specifying the file path, can someone please explain to me why it is required to use the path in XE 5? I use XE 5 at home and 2010 at school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filename `'Some.txt'` is a relative path. Relative paths are relative to the process working directory. Often, but not always, the working directory is the same as the executable directory. Clearly the working directory in your process, whatever it happens to be, does not contain a file of that name.

If you are unsure of what the process working directory is, call [`GetCurrentDir`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.GetCurrentDir).

The question that you need to ask yourself, if how you expect the program to find this text file. Where should the text file be located? In the same directory as the executable? If so, then be prepared not to be able to write to the file, due to UAC when your program resides under the program files directory. Or should the file be located in the user's profile? Or perhaps a system wide location rather than per-user. Only when you have a clear idea of where you want the file to be can you decide how to locate it.

Comment: Is there anyway to see where the program is trying to locate the file from? I tried moving the program and the .txt file to the same user, in which the program is installed, but i still receive the same error.

Comment: Yes, it's the working directory, as I said. Use `GetCurrentDir` to query that.

Comment: Well, I seemed to get it working. I added an additional button, added the GetCurrentDir to it and add that into a RichEdit, then pasted the .txt into that Dir. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If you wanna get the location of your executable you can use ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName); but bare in mind that as David Hefferman already sad you might not have writing perimisions to the folder in which your executable is located due to windows security settings. So this can come usefull when trying to get location of some resource files you read into your application. But if you want to write some data into that file then you should either use users documents directory if the data is user specific or app data folder if data is application specific.